# Passing environment variables from Dockerfile to app code

Tags: docker, dockerfile, continuous-integration, environment-variables, github-actions

I have an environment variable on my server (local raspberry pi) that stores a token that I need. When I run the docker container myself, it doesn't seem to have any problems getting the token from the environment variable. The variable is exported in my `.bashrc` and can be seen with `echo`.

**When running a workflow through github actions with the same steps, the application cannot find the token.**

The environment variable is consistently not there when I check for it. After thinking maybe it was having trouble accessing my `.bashrc` file, I made a github secret and have been trying to pass the value referencing that instead as you can see below.

I have these lines in my Dockerfile:

```
ARG MY_TOKEN
ENV MY_TOKEN=$MY_TOKEN
```

And this is my workflow yaml:

```
docker build --build-arg MY_TOKEN=${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN }} -t my_img ~/my_project
docker run -de MY_TOKEN --restart=always --name=my_container my_img
```

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated, I feel like I could get this to work by passing system arguments but

1. I'm unsure if that's good practice
2. I'd feel better if someone could point out my bonehead mistake thats holding me back before doing something else

Comment: Remove `e MY_TOKEN` it's already there. Or `-e MY_TOKEN=${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN }}`

Comment: @KamilCuk Somehow didn't catch that/didn't realize that would cause it to fail like that. Like I said, bonehead mistake. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you can start the container with a `docker run -e` option passing the token in, that will provide a value and will override anything that might be set in the image.  That means you can delete the `ARG` and the `docker build --build-arg` option, which store the token in plain text in the image.

Comment: 1) If your app wants to consume environment variables at runtime, then the values should be passed when the container is launched (part of `docker run`), not during image build (part of `docker build`). 2) If what you really want to pass is a secret (not a general environment variable), your best option is something like the standard secret management API, https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/